# Printing A Certain Value from an Array in MatLab

Tags: arrays, matlab

Okay so I have some code that is similar to the following:

a = [1 2 3 4]

b = [0.1 0.2 0.7 0.6]

c = [12 5 6 1]

d = [0 4 7 13]

x = (12 * (a + 1) .^ 2 + (b .* c)) - d

And what I want to do is print how much x would be for each for each set of values. The reason I chose an array was because I want to use the first values of all a, b, c, d together and the second values together and so on. I want to fprintf x but don't know how to do that without only getting the last value. I am clueless what to do. Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

```
result = [a b c d x];
fprintf('a\t%7.2f\nb\t%7.2f\nc\t%7.2f\nd\t%7.2f\t\nx\t%7.f\n\n',result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
x = (12 * (a + 1) .^ 2 + (b .* c)) - d
```

If I remember Matlab correctly you should get an array of 4 numbers, each number is the result for 1st element in a, b, c,d, 2nd element etc.

Comment: Haha, sorry I was just making up an example. I'm aware that I need to do this, I've done it in my code. I'm just curious how I could print the four resulting x values

Comment: I want to have fprintf statements where I can be ('The value of x is %f', x) for the four

Comment: but why don't you just print the array x? 1st element is 1st column aggregation, 2nd element is 2nd column aggregation and so forth. Or I don't completely understand your needs :)

Comment: like this http://ocw.uci.edu/upload/files/mae10_w2011_lecture08.pdf ?
fprintf('The value of x is %7f', x)

Comment: I see where you are coming from. I want to have it in sentences if that makes sense. So in the command window when it prints I want four statements that tell me the value for each rather than just numbers outputted. So that the person reading can understand from the sentence which ones correlate to one another

Comment: okay, I see. You can do this in a loop or if you only have fixed small number of elements you can do something like fprintf('First column aggregation = %f\n 2nd column aggregation = %f ...', x[0], x[1]). Loop example should be fairly simple too, I just have to search more examples on the web as I didn't open matlab/octave for at least a year

Comment: Thank you Borys Zibrov for helping me with this